# I'm getting an error in Amazon SP-API Orders API "Application do not have access to some or all requested resource"

Tags: php, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm getting an error "Application do not have access to some or all requested resource" when calling the method getOrders()/getOrder() from the Orders API.

I taken the code entirely from https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api. I installed the `composer require jlevers/selling-partner-api` and followed the instruction to connect to the Selling Partner API.

In addition, I also tried calling `$result = $apiInstance>getMarketplaceParticipations()` which works without any particular error, so I don't think it's an error in the configurations.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Code

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
    
$token = "<TOKEN>";
    
    use SellingPartnerApi\Api\SellersV1Api as SellersApi;
    use SellingPartnerApi\Configuration;
    use SellingPartnerApi\Endpoint;
    
    $config = new Configuration([
        "lwaClientId" => "amzn1.applica..",
        "lwaClientSecret" => "<clientSecret>",
        "lwaRefreshToken" => $token,
        "awsAccessKeyId" => "<accessKey>",
        "awsSecretAccessKey" => "<secretAcessKey>",
        "endpoint" => Endpoint::FE
    ]);
    
    $apiInstance = new SellingPartnerApi\Api\OrdersV0Api($config);
    $marketplace_ids = array('A1############'); 
    $created_after = '2022-07-27';
    
    try {
        $result = $apiInstance->getOrders($marketplace_ids);

        print "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        print "</pre>";
    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    
        echo 'Exception when calling OrdersV0Api->getOrders: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Error Message

```
Exception when calling OrdersV0Api->getOrders: [400] { "errors": [ { "code": "InvalidInput", "message": "Application do not have access to some or all requested resource", "details": "" } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put created after in this format:

```
$created_after = new \DateTime("2021-10-01");
$after_str = $created_after->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```